# assigning weights to trendlines in c

Tags: c, arrays, permutation

I am trying to assign a set of weights to a set of trendlines.
The weights are in an array, and the trendlines are in an array.  I want to
end up with all the permutation: ie, so each trendLine in the array gets
assigned each weight.  In my code I am currently getting this output:

```
output: 1 combination per line:
1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00 
1.50, 1.50, 1.50, 1.50 
2.00, 2.00, 2.00, 2.00,
```

But what I am trying to get is all the permutations, excluding duplicates.  That is
I want to get all the different possible combinations of weights/trendlines:

```
output: 1 combination per line:
1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00
1.50, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 
2.50, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 
1.00, 1.50, 1.00, 1.00, 
1.50, 1.50, 1.00, 1.00, 
2.50, 1.50, 1.00, 1.00, 
....etc
```

Edit:
So my question is: how do I change the code below so I can produce
 all the different combinations of trendlines and weights.  For example, if I had 2 trendlines and  3 weights (1,2,3), all the combinations would be:

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
3,1
3,2
3,3
```

Here is the code:

```
#define TRENDLINE_COUNT 4
#define WEIGHT_COUNT 3
void hhour(void)
{   
    int trendLine[TRENDLINE_COUNT];
    double weight[] = { 1, 1.5, 2 };
    FILE *myFile = fopen("s:\\data\\testdump\\ww.txt", WRITE);

    fprintf(myFile, "output: 1 combination per line :\n"    );
    for (int weightIndex = 0; wei`enter code here`ghtIndex < WEIGHT_COUNT; weightIndex++)
    {
        double currentWeight = weight[weightIndex];
        double cumulativeTrendValue = 0;

        for (int trendLineIndex = 0; trendLineIndex < TRENDLINE_COUNT; trendLineIndex++)
        {
            cumulativeTrendValue += trendLine[trendLineIndex] * currentWeight;

            fprintf(myFile, "%.02lf, ", currentWeight);
        }
        fprintf(myFile, "\n");

        // do something with cumulativeTrendValue
    }

    fclose(myFile);
}
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question and pretend that we don't know what you know about your problem? Maybe I'm the only one but I couldn't figure out what your question actually is.

Comment: Sorr about that.  Ok, I tried to add a bit more explanation to the original post.

Comment: So.... If I'm reading this right... the number of lines is a [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of the trandline?  2 and 2 were bad example numbers, this isn't clear at all.

Comment: Ok, I edited to clarify.  It now shows 2 trendlines and 3 weights.  Doing this manually: if there are 2 trendlines and 3 weights, there are 9 unique combinations (which I wrote out in  the  edited post).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're after. Gimme a minute and I'll have some code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. There are probably cleaner solutions out there but I'm a big fan of brute forcing solutions when possible. If you want to vary the trendline... uh, maybe something with a recursive variadic function... but I start charging when facing that level of insantiy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRENDLINE_COUNT 4
#define WEIGHT_COUNT 3

double weight[] = { 1, 1.5, 2 };

int addOne(int counter[TRENDLINE_COUNT])
{
  int i=0;
  while(1)
  {
    if(counter[i]+1 >= WEIGHT_COUNT)
    {
      if( i+1 >= TRENDLINE_COUNT)
      {  return 1;}
      else
      { 
        counter[i]=0;
        i++;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      counter[i]++;
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void hhr()
{
  int i;
  int counter[TRENDLINE_COUNT];  

  memset(counter, 0, sizeof(int)*TRENDLINE_COUNT);
  do 
  {
    for(i=0; i<TRENDLINE_COUNT; i++)
    { 
      //printf("%d ", counter[i]);
      printf("%f ", weight[counter[i]]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }while(!addOne(counter));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  hhr();
}
```